# combining columns of 2 files using shell script

Tags: shell, join, command-line

I have one.txt

```
A B
C D
E F
```

and two.txt

```
H
J
N
```

How can I add 3rd column to one.txt like:

```
A B H
C D J
E F N
```

I want to do this using shell script .. is there any command which can help?

Answer (score 7):

`paste` to the rescue. `-d` stands for "delimiter" and I set it to "space".

```
$ paste -d' ' one.txt two.txt
A B H
C D J
E F N
```

If you want the result to be stored in `one.txt`, you can save it in a temporary file and then replace `one.txt` with it:

```
$ paste -d' ' one.txt two.txt > temp && mv temp one.txt
```

Comment: +1. Join the `paste` and `mv` commands with `&&` -- don't want to overwrite the file with garbage if paste fails for any reason